# @select annotation Example in JDBC4

Tags: jdbc

I have searched in net and i got examples which use java.sql.BaseQuery interface but i am not able to see the interface in the java api documentation. Can anyone share me the link for using @select annotation example

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing in JDBC. It was proposed for JDBC 4, but was dropped before the specification was finalized.